# Change opacity of button/s over mouse hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4 `button`s. I am trying to lighten `opacity` upon `hover`.

**PROBLEM:** Every time I `hover`, all 4 `button`s change `opacity` to lighten and I only would like 1 `button` at a time to change `opacity` upon `hover`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').mouseenter(function() {
       $('button').fadeTo('fast', 1);
   });
       $('button').mouseleave(function() {
       $('button').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
   });
   });
```

NOT WORKING

Need good solutions from you smart peoples!

Comment: you want only the button being hovered to change the opacity right ?

Comment: Use `$(this)` instead of `$(button)`

Comment: Please share your html code.

Comment: I did something like this before and I still can't get it...                                   /* $(".navigation").text("Testing!");   */   
$(".print, .digital, .email, .ux").hover(
 function() {
  $( this ).addClass ( "hover" );
 }, function() {
  $( this ).removeClass ( "hover" );
 } 
;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use `$(this)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').mouseenter(function() {
     $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
   });
   $('button').mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
   });
   
 });
```

```css
button {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">button1</button>
<button id="button2">button2</button>
<button id="button3">button3</button>
<button id="button4">button4</button>
```

or you can to use `ID` on each `button`  , which is a lot more code, but still a solution.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#button1').mouseenter(function() {
     $('#button1').fadeTo('fast', 1);
   });
   $('#button1').mouseleave(function() {
     $('#button1').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
   });
   $('#button2').mouseenter(function() {
     $('#button2').fadeTo('fast', 1);
   });
   $('#button2').mouseleave(function() {
     $('#button2').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
   });
   $('#button3').mouseenter(function() {
     $('#button3').fadeTo('fast', 1);
   });
   $('#button3').mouseleave(function() {
     $('#button3').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
   });
   $('#button4').mouseenter(function() {
     $('#button4').fadeTo('fast', 1);
   });
   $('#button4').mouseleave(function() {
     $('#button4').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
   });
 });
```

```css
button {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">button1</button>
<button id="button2">button2</button>
<button id="button3">button3</button>
<button id="button4">button4</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have classes within the html per button. Here's what it looks like:      <li>
      <img src="images/CA7B4D0A9A.jpg" alt="Print & Illustration " height="250" width="250">
       <div class="caption">
       <h5>Print & Illustration </h5>
       <button class="print">
        <a href="">Check it out</a>
       </button>
       </div>
     </li>

Comment: and what I'm supposed to with that? :) there is nothing wrong with that code :).

If this solves your issue, you should mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: I will but it's still not working :/ Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have the correct . and # selectors ......

Comment: IT WORKED!! LOL blonde moment! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` or rather `$(this)` within the functions to get a reference to the button that triggered the event.

```
$('button').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
$('button').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8w0mw2ak/

Answer (score 0):

All above answers are great!

But If you are just looking for the effect, you can use CSS3 and a couple of tricks too!

Taken from: https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/css-transitions-buttons/

```css
button {
  background: #428BCA;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 25px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

/** Effect **/
button {
  opacity: 1;
}
button:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button>Fade -2</button>
  <button>Fade -1</button>
  <button>Fade 1</button>
  <button>Fade 2</button>
  <button>Fade 3</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with the button segment I'm support to incorporate within the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

use $(this)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).fadeTo('fast', .5);
});
   $('button').mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this) inside the function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('button').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
    $('button').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    });
});
```